# ARC deallocate my NSmutablearray before NSTableview reloaddata

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

My NSMutableArray lOfSegments, declared as IVAR, get populated correctly. During the debug it shows 4 object in the array.

```
for (int x=0; [arrayOfSegmentsTcIn count]>x; x++) {

    NSDictionary *segmentDic=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:   [arrayOfSegmentsNumbers objectAtIndex:x],@"segment",[arrayOfSegmentsTcIn objectAtIndex:x],@"tc_in",[arrayOfSegmentsTcOut objectAtIndex:x],@"tc_out", nil];
    [lOfSegments addObject:segmentDic];
    [myDMXML.segments addObject:segmentDic];

}

[self.xmlTCLable setStringValue:[myDMXML startTimeCode]];
[self.xmlDurationLable setStringValue:[myDMXML duration]];
[self xmlValidationCheck];
NSLog(@"arrayController:%@",[lOfSegments valueForKey:@"segment"]);
[self.tableViewOutlet reloadData];
```

NSLog list the array correctly but when reloadData is executed the code jumps to

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
return [lOfSegments count];
}
```

The array is null.

The Object is initialised in viewDidLoad as

```
lOfSegments  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Please Help!

Comment: Can you show more code? Why an ivar and not a property? Can you show the rest of your `UITableViewDataSource` protocol code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend making your code more clear here by using `self.lOfSegments` rather than directly accessing an ivar. (The fact that the ivar lacks a leading `_` is very suspicious as well, and raises the question of whether this is even the variable you think it is.)

On the assumption that this is the variable you think it is, and that you have overridden the standard behavior to make the ivar match the property or created explicit ivars (neither of which you should do), there are several common causes for this kind of problem:

- The most likely cause is that you called your initialization code prior to `viewDidLoad` and then `viewDidLoad` blew away the array. Many things can run prior to `viewDidLoad`, and `viewDidLoad` can run more than once (at least this used to be true; I'd have to study whether the view-loading changes in iOS 6 made it guaranteed to be run once.)
- You have some other way reset `lOfSegments` between the time your initialization code ran and the time `reloadData` ran. If you would reliably use `self.` then you could override `setLOfSegments:` so you could log this. Or you could mark this property readonly so you could prevent it. Thats one of many reasons that you should use properties, not ivars.
- The setting code failed to run before `reloadData`. Ensure that the log statement actually printed prior to getting to `reloadData` and is on the same queue (the queue identifier will be part of the `NSLog` output in brackets). I don't think this is likely given your description, but it is a common problem.
- There are two instances of this object. Make sure that the object that ran your initialization code is the same object that ran `reloadData`. This is a more common mistake then you may think. Log `self` and make sure the memory address is the same in both cases.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your time. I've tried to use a property instead but it makes no difference. The property was declared as (nonatomic, retain). And the dot notation was used.

Comment: And you tried overriding `setLOfSegments:` to see when it's called in relation to `reloadData`?

Comment: In fact, you are right, the reload data calls a different object. They have completely different memory address and if I try to load more data in the array it keeps growing but reloadData calls an object that is nil. How  I avoid this?

Comment: tis is the log of self:
2015-02-20 12:04:26.832 MXFmetadataReader[83087:2141839] Self1:<ViewController: 0x6000001e2e00>
2015-02-20 12:04:27.668 MXFmetadataReader[83087:2141839] Self2:<ViewController: 0x6000001e2f00>

Comment: Thanks It works. I had two instances of viewController!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have variable with same name `lOfSegments` in method `viewDidLoad`. So in `viewDidLoad` you use stack variable, in `numberOfRowsInTableView` - instance variable.

Or maybe `tableViewOutlete.dataSource` pointing on different `viewController`